# i am getting error AttributeError: 'Auth' object has no attribute 'get_user' in Flask App

Tags: python, firebase-authentication

```
from firebase_admin import auth

@app.route("/admin/dashboard")
def admin_dashboard():
    current_user = auth.get_user(request.cookies.get("session"))
    # If the user is not authenticated, redirect to the login page
    if not current_user:
        return redirect(url_for('/admin/login'))
    return render_template("admin/dashboard.html")
```

i am getting following error "current_user = auth.get_user(request.cookies.get("session"))
AttributeError: 'Auth' object has no attribute 'get_user'"

Comment: post the full error please.

Comment: File "D:\EBMFit\app\admin_views.py", line 13, in admin_dashboard
    current_user = auth.get_user(request.cookies.get("session"))
AttributeError: 'Auth' object has no attribute 'get_user'
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Dec/2022 14:15:36] "GET /admin/dashboard HTTP/1.1" 500 -
this is the error i am getting

Answer (score 0):

You need to use class Client in module `auth`:

```
from firebase_admin import auth

@app.route("/admin/dashboard")
def admin_dashboard():
    current_user = auth.Client.get_user(request.cookies.get("session"))
    # If the user is not authenticated, redirect to the login page
    if not current_user:
        return redirect(url_for('/admin/login'))
    return render_template("admin/dashboard.html")
```

More detail is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth)

Comment: File "D:\EBMFit\app\admin_views.py", line 13, in admin_dashboard
    current_user = auth.Client.get_user(request.cookies.get("session"))
AttributeError: 'Auth' object has no attribute 'Client'
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Dec/2022 14:24:35] "GET /admin/dashboard HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: import json
from flask import request, render_template, session, redirect, url_for
from app import app
from firebase import Firebase
from firebase_admin import auth


firebase = Firebase(json.load(open('firebase_config.json')))
auth = firebase.auth()

@app.route("/admin/dashboard")
def admin_dashboard():
    current_user = auth.Client.get_user(request.cookies.get("session"))
    # If the user is not authenticated
    if not current_user:
        return redirect(url_for('/admin/login'))
    return render_template("admin/dashboard.html")